# How to show and hide QtGui.QGridLayout in PySide

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyside

Here I am creating a layout called `_grid` and putting few labels and slider in the layout .

Now I want this layout to be hide first then `onclick` I want to show it .

If there is any simple function associated with  `QtGui.QGridLayout`  to show and hide.

I googled and found this is available for `QWidget` by  `QWidget.hide()`

```
class TimeSlider (QtGui.QVBoxLayout):
 def __init__ (self):
    QtGui.QVBoxLayout.__init__ (self)


    # Put everything in a grid
    _grid = QtGui.QGridLayout ()
    self.addLayout (_grid)

    # Slider limit labels

    _grid.addWidget (QtGui.QLabel (''), 0, 0)
    _labelLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout ()
    _grid.addLayout (_labelLayout, 0, 1)
    self.lower = QtGui.QLabel ('LOW')


    _labelLayout.addWidget (self.lower)
    self.higher = QtGui.QLabel ('HIGH')
    self.higher.setAlignment (QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

    _labelLayout.addWidget (self.higher)

    # Slider

    _grid.addWidget (QtGui.QLabel (''), 1, 0)
    self.sliderBarLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout ()
    self.sliderBarLayout.setSpacing (0)
    _grid.addLayout (self.sliderBarLayout, 1, 1)

    self.sliderBarLayout.addWidget (self.leftEndstop)

    self.slider = QtGui.QSlider (QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    self.slider.setTickPosition (QtGui.QSlider.TicksBelow)
    self.slider.setTracking (True)
    self.slider.setMinimumWidth (40)
    self.slider.setPageStep (1)

    self.sliderBarLayout.addWidget (self.slider)

    self.rightEndstop = RightEndstop (self, self.root)

    self.sliderBarLayout.addWidget (self.rightEndstop)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class TimeSlider (QtGui.QVBoxLayout):
    def __init__ (self):
        QtGui.QVBoxLayout.__init__ (self)
        # Put everything in a grid
        _manLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout ()
        self._frame = QtGui.QFrame();
        _manLayout.addWidget(self._frame)
        _grid = QtGui.QGridLayout (self._frame)

        # Slider limit labels

        _grid.addWidget (QtGui.QLabel (''), 0, 0)
        _labelLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout ()
        _grid.addLayout (_labelLayout, 0, 1)
        self.lower = QtGui.QLabel ('LOW')


        _labelLayout.addWidget (self.lower)
        self.higher = QtGui.QLabel ('HIGH')
        self.higher.setAlignment (QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        _labelLayout.addWidget (self.higher)

        # Slider

        _grid.addWidget (QtGui.QLabel (''), 1, 0)
        self.sliderBarLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout ()
        self.sliderBarLayout.setSpacing (0)
        _grid.addLayout (self.sliderBarLayout, 1, 1)

        # self.sliderBarLayout.addWidget (self.leftEndstop)

        self.slider = QtGui.QSlider (QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setTickPosition (QtGui.QSlider.TicksBelow)
        self.slider.setTracking (True)
        self.slider.setMinimumWidth (40)
        self.slider.setPageStep (1)

        self.sliderBarLayout.addWidget (self.slider)
        self._frame.setLayout(_grid)
        self.addLayout (_manLayout)

        #self.rightEndstop = RightEndstop (self, self.root)

        # self.sliderBarLayout.addWidget (self.rightEndstop)
    def show(self):
        self._frame.show()
    def hide(self):
        self._frame.hide()
    def isHidden(self):
        return self._frame.isHidden()



class NewTimeSliderTest(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, total=20):
        super(NewTimeSliderTest, self).__init__(parent)
        self.newTimeSlider = TimeSlider()
        self.resize(841, 474)
        self.newTimeSlider.hide()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Show/Hide')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        main_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button, 0, 0)
        main_layout.addLayout(self.newTimeSlider, 0, 1)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self._active = False

    def handleButton(self):
        #self.newTimeSlider.show()
        isHidden = self.newTimeSlider.isHidden()
        if isHidden:
            self.newTimeSlider.show()
        else:
            self.newTimeSlider.hide()


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
bar = NewTimeSliderTest(total=101)
bar.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How about this ?

Any time you can all like this.

```
self.newTimeSlider.show()
```

or

```
self.newTimeSlider.hide()
```

Comment: `_grid = QtGui.QGridLayout (self._frame)` here i am getting the error `QLayout::addChildLayout: layout "" already has a parent`

Comment: I just updated the code with working example.. Commented some lines like RightEndstop coz don't know from where its coming.

Comment: Its working for me :) Do you getting some error ?. then please show us the traceback

Comment: Strange I am not getting any error now , but  hide is not working for me :(

Comment: Updated with proper show/hide button. Hope that make sense